# Getting data race condition with zerolog

Tags: go

I am using zerolog configured with diodes to prevent a race condition when writing to stdout.  This is my log setup:

```
consoleWriter := zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stdout, NoColor: *logNoColor, TimeFormat: *logDateTimeFormat}
return diode.NewWriter(consoleWriter, 1000, 10*time.Millisecond, onMissedMessages)
```

I am following the example from here:
[zerolog documentation](https://github.com/rs/zerolog)

Finally, I set the global logger with the writer returned from above (f):

```
log.Logger = zerolog.New(f).With().Timestamp().Logger()
```

I have a shutdown hook (listens for CTRL+C) which basically just writes a log message when it is called and cancels the root context.  I am also writing a log message after 1 second has elapsed using the time.After function.

When I don't press CTRL+C, the application runs as expected; however, when I press CTRL+C prior to the 1 second delayed execution of a method, I get a data race condition.  When I remove the log statements, the problem goes away leading me to believe that the diode setup from above isn't helping prevent a race condition.

Just to make sure I'm understanding how golang works:

1. Canceling a context releases resources tied to that context.  Ie. if you have a child context with a channel and close the child context, only that channel would be closed / released
2. os.Stdout, os.Stderr, etc. are not thread-safe and operations on them must be controlled by the developer.
3. I can check if a context is Done() from numerous goroutines without a synchronization problem.  However, I can and should only read from a channel from a single thread

Comment: Canceling a context doesn’t release any resources by itself. Stdout and stderr are thread safe, but it makes no sense to write to a stream concurrently. Contexts and channels are safe to use from multiple goroutines, as that is their primary purpose. Show an actual example with the locations of the race if you need assistance.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong (https://golang.org/pkg/context/): Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete.

Comment: That’s uncharacteristically imprecise for the docs. The context itself isn’t releasing anything, however it’s often associated with some resources, which is usually why you’re using it. Yes, you should logically cancel the context as soon as possible, and no it will not cancel contexts not derived from the one you’re cancelling. Without a [mre] it’s hard to know what you’re actually doing. You haven’t even shown what the data race is.

Comment: I rewrote my libraries and am no longer getting the race condition. I also started several goroutines that just logged and that had no issues. I haven't spotted the problem, but have a better way of doing what I wanted to accomplish, without getting the race condition.